# Printing two variable on the same line after using .split() method

Tags: python

I have an output saved in a txt file like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
localpref 300,
-----------------------------------------------------------------
via et-0/1/5.0
-----------------------------------------------------------------
localpref 300
-----------------------------------------------------------------
via et-0/1/5.0
-----------------------------------------------------------------
localpref 300,
-----------------------------------------------------------------
via ae0.0
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

to write it I used this code:

```
    with open((open_file), 'r') as LP:
       all_data = LP.readlines()
       key = ['localpref', 'via']
       for lines in all_data:
        for words in key:
           if words in lines:
            list_of_words = lines.split()
            LPV_INT = list_of_words[list_of_words.index(words) + 1]
            print('-'*65)
            print(f'{words} {LPV_INT}')
            sys.stdout.flush()
```

I tried without success to have an output like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
localpref 300, via et-0/1/5.0
-----------------------------------------------------------------
localpref 300 via et-0/1/5.0
-----------------------------------------------------------------
localpref 300, via ae0.0
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can someone point me out in the right direction?

Thanks!

EDIT1

Changes after @Sn3nS suggestions:

```
with open((open_file), 'r') as LP:
   all_data = LP.readlines()
   keys = ['localpref', 'via']
   for line in all_data:
        if keys[0] in line and keys[1] in line:
            splitted = line.splitlines()
            LPV_INT0 = splitted[splitted.index((keys[0])) + 1]
            LPV_INT1 = splitted[splitted.index((keys[1])) + 1]
            print('-'*65)
            print(f'{keys[0]} {LPV_INT0} {keys[1]} {LPV_INT1}')
```

No errors on running it unfortunatelly now the script print anything on the file, definitely I'm missing again something but I don't know what

Comment: You can have a look to the `end` parameter of the function `print`. If you want to print something without a newline at the end, use `print("my super text", end="")`.

Answer (score 0):

What happens in your code is that for each of your keywords you have one print operation, because here:

```
for words in key:
   if words in lines:
```

you execute the if-block once for `localpref` and once for `via` and in the if you have your print.

What you could do is instead of doing this:

```
for lines in all_data:
    for words in key:
       if words in lines:
       ...
```

is doing this:

```
for lines in all_data:
    if key[0] in lines and key[1] in lines:
        ...
```

and then later change your print statement to something like:

```
print(f'{key[0]} {LPV_INT0} {key[1]} {LPV_INT1}')
```

Of course you would have to do the next word thing with `LPV_INTx` for both keys then.

On a side note I would recommend calling your variables `line` instead of `lines` (and `word` instead of `words`) because these variables represent  only one item each and rename `key` to `keys` as it holds more then one element that you use as a key.

### Edit based on your edit

The error is in this line:

```
splitted = line.splitlines()
```

It needs to be (like before):

```
splitted = line.split()
```

That should fix it :D

Comment: thanks for this suggestion, just to point out, need I to insert the `if` statement suggested after `for words in key:` or before `for lines in all_data:`

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify what I mean :)

Comment: I edited again :)